# More compact way to write ajax queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios

I have been writing many web apps with php & mysql & jquery & bootstrap and now it's time address this problem. How to write shorter ajax queries(posting) ? 
If I want to write code that works and takes care of many problems, it's too long for every ajax call.
Is there a better way or some library / wrapper that makes the code SHORTER and FASTER to write, but does atleast all these stuff

I looked popular axios, but it seems even worse

```
//JUST an example code, too complicated
var $btnStatusElem = $("#passwordreset").button('loading');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "pwreset.php",
    data: postdata
    success: function(data) {
        $btnStatusElem.button('reset');
        try {
            var datajson = JSON.parse(data);
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert('Unexpected server error');
            return false;
        };

        if (datajson['success'] == true) {
            //do the OK stuff 
        } else {
            //show the error code, and stuff
            return false;
        }

},//success
error: function(msg) {
    alert('ERROR');
    $('#passwordreset_result').html(msg);
}
});
```

For my code, ajax query, i want it to do these steps:
1. Disable the submit button while posting (re-enable also after 15 seconds and not just leave it disabled until page refresh)
2. It sends json, expects json to return
3. If server has some error, it DOES NOT return json but error. Then the code will halt all js execution if i dont use try...catch. This is pain to write each time
4. If server returns validation error or some other expected error, i have to detect this and show to the user 
5. If all ok, do the stuff

Comment: For *one* query, this looks quite reasonable, there isn't much at all to improve. If you have multiple repetitive looking queries, please post them as well, so we can see what the repetitiveness is like

Comment: You can really only make this more DRY if you have lots more WET code.

Comment: the more simple and short is Fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch

Answer (score 1):

As with any refactoring, identify and isolate the repetitive code and pass in the unique bits. In this case, for example, you could isolate the ajax call and json parsing into a function and pass in the url, data, etc.

That function could return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) that resolves/rejects as appropriate.

Given the `doRequest` function below (pseudocode, untested and would probably need a bit of tweaking for real-world use), you could then use it all over the place with fewer keystrokes:

```
doRequest('pwreset.php', postdata, button)
  .then(result => {
    // do something with the result
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // deal with the error
  });
```

or

```
try {
  const result = await doRequest('pwreset.php', postdata);
  // do something with result
}
catch (e) {
  // handle error
}
```

All of the boilerplate stuff is isolated in `doRequest`.

```
async function doRequest(url, data, button, type = "POST") {
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      type,
      url,
      data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $btnStatusElem.button('reset');
        try {
          const datajson = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (e) {
          return reject(e);
        };

        return datajson['success'] == true ?
          fulfill(datajson) :
          reject(datajson);
      }, //success
      error: function(msg) {
        return reject(msg);
      }
    });
  })
}
```

As [@mister-jojo says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267014/more-compact-way-to-write-ajax-queries#comment99150159_56267014), you might also want to consider using the [fetch api] instead of jQuery, but the same principle applies.